# VBA - Runtime Error when clicking out of rich text field on ms-word

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, ms-office

Not super familiar with VBA, so I feel like this may be a fairly simplistic question, but I can't find a resolution for my issue.

In ms-word, I've made a form in which initially, I wanted specific aspects of the form to hide/display based on different interactions with the form (code down below), which, with some help from another post, works fine, but now I've added text-fields which is causing run-time errors.

Now my issue is that the ContentControlOnExit function is being applied to when a user clicks out of a text field, which I only wanted to apply to when a user clicks out of a chechkbox, which is causing run-time error's.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim bChecked As Boolean
    bChecked = (ContentControl.Checked = True)

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox1" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("approve").Range.Font.Hidden = bChecked
    End If

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox2" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sign1").Range.Font.Hidden = bChecked
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("sign2").Range.Font.Hidden = bChecked
    End If

    If ContentControl.Title = "checkbox3" Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("note").Range.Font.Hidden = bChecked
    End If

End Sub
```

Is there any simple statement I can add so that it doesn't do this check when clicking out of a text-field?

Comment: Cross-posted at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-runtime-error-when-clicking-out-of-rich-text/86c65656-127a-48df-9cb3-604833b17676 For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 0):

You can use the content control's `Type` property to check if it's a checkbox:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.contentcontrol.type

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, _
                                          Cancel As Boolean)
    'exit if the control is not a checkbox
    If ContentControl.Type <> wdContentControlCheckbox Then Exit Sub

    'rest of your code here         

End Sub
```